# Exception in sqoop export

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

I am exporting data from HDFS to sql server. I have used the follwing command

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:portno;database=dbname;user=xxxx;password=passwd" --table sample --export-dir /sample
```

But I am getting login failed for user xxxx. But credentials are correct in the command. Can any one tell me why?

Comment: will you please show more error logs you got...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too simple to be true, but I think the connectionstring property for the user should be username instead of user.

Can you try it like this?

`sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:portno;database=dbname;username=xxxx;password=passwd" --table sample --export-dir /sampl`

Comment: Hi..I have tried username instead of user but still faces the same issue

Comment: Are you able to try integrated security?

Comment: Hi...but I have connected to db and can query data from db using java code